# Meteor show update field instead of item if update clicked

Tags: meteor

I have the simplest Meteor project ever, but I'm stuck at something basic.  I have one form field, and when I enter an item it goes into a Mongo collection.  I retrieve and display that collection, along with buttons to delete or edit.  What I want to happen is you click edit, and the item becomes a text box (prepopulated with the original value) that you can change, hit return, and have the item updated.  I'm stuck at how to pass the _id along properly and/or how to convert only the correct entry into a field.

My .html file:

```
<head>
  <title>Memorial</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Memorial Testing!</h1>

<form class="new-task">
    <input type="text" name="text" placehoder="Type stuff here" />
</form>
    {{> listing}}
</body>


<template name="listing">
    <ul>
        {{#each tasks}}
            {{> crudlist}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="crudlist">
    {{#if editor}}
        {{#if editid == this._id}}
            <li><input type="text" name="text" placehoder="Type stuff here" value="{{text}}"/></li>
        {{else}}
            <li>{{text}} :: <button name="delete" class="delete">Delete</button><button name="edit" class="edit">Edit</button></li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

My .js file:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.listing.helpers({
    tasks: function() {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });

  Template.crudlist.helpers({
    editor: function() {
      return Session.get("editor");
    },
    editid: function() {
      return Session.get("editid");
    }
  });


  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      var text = event.target.text.value;

      Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date()
      });
      event.target.text.value = "";
      return false;
    }
  });


  Template.crudlist.events({
    "click .delete": function () {
      Tasks.remove(this._id);
    },
    "click .edit": function () {
      Session.set("editor","true");
      Session.set("editid",this._id);
    }
  });
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you've just clicked on you should use event.target from the documentation http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps.

```
Template.crudlist.events({
    "click .delete": function (event,template) {
      var whatYouJustClicked = event.target,
          targetID = $(whatYouJustClicked).attr('id')
    },
    "click .edit": function (event,template) {
      var whatYouJustClicked = event.target,
          targetID = $(whatYouJustClicked).attr('id')
      Session.set("editor","true");
      Session.set("editid",targetID);
    }
```

});